# navigation doesn't work in primefaces carousel

Tags: jsf-2, navigation, primefaces, carousel

I need to set some values in my model and navigate page to another one but nothing happens on button click(neither page navigated nor method triggered)....My code works perfect outside the carousel but inside carousel its doesn't work(no page navigation)

```
<p:carousel value="#{catalog.getServices()}" var="s" rows="1">
    <h:outputLabel for="id" value="Service ID " />
    <h:outputText id="id" value="#{s.id}" />
    <br></br>
    <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Service Name" />
    <h:outputText id="name" value="#{s.name}" />
    <br />
    <h:commandLink action="detail">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{s}" target="#{sh.currentService}" />
    <h:commandButton value="getService" style="float:right;" />
    </h:commandLink>
</p:carousel>
```

And my navigation works perfect outside this carousel

```
<h:commandLink action="detail">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{s}" target="#{sh.currentService}" />
    <h:commandButton value="getService" style="float:right;" />
</h:commandLink>
```

Above code can make my page navigate and method which I want to trigger is also working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid nesting `h:commandButton` inside `h:commandLink`.

Simply use  `h:commandButton` this way:

```
<h:commandButton value="getService" action="#{yourBean.yourActionMethod}">
  <f:setPropertyActionListener .../>
</h:commandButton>
```

And in your backing bean return the navigation target as result from the action method:

```
public String yourActionMethod() {
  // do your stuff here
  return "detail";
}
```

Comment: <p:carousel rows="1">

<p:commandButton value="Click me" action="#{controller.navigate}"></p:commandButton>
</p:carousel>  Even this is not working for me....when i am having this command button outside carousel its working fine....

Comment: You should check if the request is triggered from the client (use the browser dev tools) and if the backing bean method is executed. You could also try a full request instead of an ajax request (set `ajax="false"` in `p:commandButton`.

Comment: backing bean method is not executed when command button is inside carousel....& i am using `h:commandButton` so i hope no need of setting `ajax="false"`... when my command button is outside carousel request is triggered from client & backing bean method is also executed...

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the commandButton inside p:column. I had this issue and here http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=16120 helped me.